# Pandas: Get duplicated rows by key, if odd keep last, if even delete

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am facing a situation where I need to deal with payments and possible reversals.

When I concatenate `SUPPLIER` with `DOC_ID` I have a key that I can identify if a row is duplicated or not. With that in mind, I would like to:

1. If a key is duplicated and if the count of duplicated rows is Even, then delete the rows from the dataset.
2. If a key is duplicated and if the count of duplicated rows is Odd, then keep last entry and delete the other duplicated values.

An example of data:

```
INDEX   SUPPLIER    DOC_ID  VALUE
1       AAA         A       -539
2       OOO         B       -946
3       NNN         C       -320
4       HHH         D       -117
5       HHH         D        117
6       OOO         E       -741
7       AAA         F       -165
8       ZZZ         G       -103
9       ZZZ         G        103
10      ZZZ         G       -103
11      BBB         H       -504
```

In the dataset above, the `SUPPLIER` of name `H` has 2 rows duplicated. These rows need to be deleted because they are canceling each other (-117+117=0).

In the other hand, the `SUPPLIER` of name `ZZZ` has 3 rows repeating. I need to keep the last entry because it is the only valid. The others are canceling each other.

The desired output:

```
INDEX   SUPPLIER    DOC_ID  VALUE
1       AAA         A       -539
2       OOO         B       -946
3       NNN         C       -320
6       OOO         E       -741
7       AAA         F       -165
10      ZZZ         G       -103
11      BBB         H       -504
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
# get the sizes
sizes = df.groupby(['SUPPLIER','DOC_ID'])['VALUE'].transform('size')

# duplicated
duplicated = df.duplicated(['SUPPLIER','DOC_ID'], keep='last')


df[(sizes%2==1)       # groups with odd number of rows
   & (~duplicated)    # and last rows
  ]
```

Output:

```
      SUPPLIER DOC_ID  VALUE
INDEX                       
1          AAA      A   -539
2          OOO      B   -946
3          NNN      C   -320
6          OOO      E   -741
7          AAA      F   -165
10         ZZZ      G   -103
11         BBB      H   -504
```

Comment: With `filter`: `df.groupby(['SUPPLIER', 'DOC_ID']).filter(lambda d: len(d) % 2 == 1).drop_duplicates(['SUPPLIER', 'DOC_ID'])`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple way of doing it if the index numbers aren't important.
Grouping by SUPPLIER and DOC_ID and summing up would cancel out the duplicates. So after that filtering out the 0 values gives you the result.

```
grouped = data.groupby(['SUPPLIER', 'DOC_ID']).agg({'VALUE' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
grouped = grouped.loc[grouped['VALUE'] != 0]
```

Which gives you this result.

```
    SUPPLIER DOC_ID VALUE
0   AAA      A      -539
1   AAA      F      -165
2   BBB      H      -504
4   NNN      C      -320
5   OOO      B      -946
6   OOO      E      -741
7   ZZZ      G      -103
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this solution would work for your case, no matter the "VALUE"

### Grouping data

```
groups = df.groupby(["SUPPLIER", "DOC_ID"]).sum("VALUE")
```

### New dataframe with the  results

```
df1 = groups.reset_index()
```

### Removing zero results

```
df1 = df1[df1["VALUE"] != 0].sort_values("DOC_ID").reset_index()
```

The result

```
   index SUPPLIER DOC_ID  INDEX  VALUE
0      0      AAA      A      1   -539
1      5      OOO      B      2   -946
2      4      NNN      C      3   -320
3      6      OOO      E      6   -741
4      1      AAA      F      7   -165
5      7      ZZZ      G     27   -103
6      2      BBB      H     11   -504
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Not A Good Answer

```
df.groupby(
    ['SUPPLIER', 'DOC_ID'],
    sort=False, as_index=False, group_keys=False
).apply(lambda d: d.tail(len(d) % 2))

    INDEX SUPPLIER DOC_ID  VALUE
0       1      AAA      A   -539
1       2      OOO      B   -946
2       3      NNN      C   -320
5       6      OOO      E   -741
6       7      AAA      F   -165
9      10      ZZZ      G   -103
10     11      BBB      H   -504
```